# Order by Desc in Node js and Mssql giving me the wrong output

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-order-by

I am working on a project where I have to call the Last data from Mssql database to check the last date and current date of the data to set the JobNumber. I was able to retrieve the data from database by execute query "Select Top 1 from TableName Order by ColumnName" But the issue arisen up when I use Order by ColumnName Desc. However, my console.log out put is give me the accurate data of the record set but when i tried to assign that record set value into a variable then the output was giving me the wrong data

my Console log out put is:

```html
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { StartTime: 2018-12-05T23:52:21.000Z, JobNumber: '113' } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
```

Image of the Variable output:

[image: Output of the image]

My Database Last Data

[image: Database LastData]

Coding for the Retrieve data

```js
var sql = "Select TOP 1 StartTime, JobNumber FROM arduino ORDER BY StartTime DESC"

    db.executeSql(sql, function (rows, err) {

        if (err) {

            console.log("Error with connection");
        }
        else {

            console.log(rows);
            var StartDateTime = rows.recordset[0].StartTime;
            var JobNumber = rows.recordset[0].JobNumber;
            var JobNum = parseInt(JobNumber);
   if(JobNum == null)

            {
                JobNo = 1;
            }

            else if (SensStart == StartDateTime)
            {
                JobNo = JobNum;
            }

            else
            {
                JobNo = JobNum + 1;
            }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by below coding

```js
  var dateString = StartDateTime;
            var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
            var momentObj = moment(dateObj);
            var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD') ;
```

Thanks